# PHP -- Using .htacess rewrite rules to hide folder name in URL

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

I'm doing a small php personal project for fun and I need help with my rewrite rules. My goal is to hide completely a folder name in my URL.

Here's what I got already :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/my-app/
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /my-app/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

This is working fine, I don't need to specify my-app folder in the URL but when I redirect to another page the folder name is displayed again. What can I do to specify that when my-app folder is requested, to hide it from the URL. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please go more in detail. About what urls your speaking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding this rule to your htaccess file:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+my-app/
RewriteRule ^my-app/(.*)$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

This will redirect any *direct request* for anything in `/my-app/` to a URL with it removed.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer and sorry for the late response, it solved by problem.